# C# ASP.NET Core IdentityServer4 wrong redirect after login when using HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 in my ASP.NET Core (v3) web application. Frontend is Angular8.

Both IdentityServer and my webapp are deployed in an IIS instance, in two web sites.

- IdentityServer -> 192.168.100.10:8080 (HTTP) and sso.mycompany.local:8443 (HTTPS)
- MyApp -> 192.168.100.10:80 (HTTP) and app.mycompany.local:443 (HTTPS)

When using HTTP (opening the browser on http://192.168.100.10) I can successfully log in via the usual web flow (myapp -> identityserver login page -> callback auth -> my app destination url)

In this scenario the url called by identity server is `http://192.168.100.10/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=[....]`
(I can see it in Chrome dev console)

When using HTTPS (opening the browser on https://myapp.company.local) the flow is wrong after identityserver auth: in Chrome dev console I see this:

`https:///connect/authorize/callback?client_id=[....]`

It looks like hostname is missing...

Please notice I am talking about the very same instance of both applications, just bound to different addresses in the same IIS instance (same configurations, same binaries, same frontend)

Comment: Can you post the client configuration in IdentityServer?

Comment: Yes, please check this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/gB549Efn


Please note that in Chrome debug console I see

`getBaseUrl - returning:https://myapp.mycompany.local`

Comment: I would check in Fiddler and try to pinpoint exactly the response that is faulty and post a copy of it here. But if the domain is missing, perhaps its confused and uses the 192.168.x.x instead of the domain? HTTPS doesn't work against IPs directly.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have privileges to install Fiddler on the only machine that has access to the application

Please check some screenshots from Chrome dev console

https://pasteboard.co/JNSu1m7.png
https://pasteboard.co/JNSwFmU.png

That highlighted HTTP 302 is the response of Identity Server

Comment: can you post your client definition in IdentityServer and your OpenIDCOnnect client startup code? (addopenidconnect..)

Comment: Are you using absolute URLs (with HTTP://domain...) or relative URL's in your redirect URL entry?

Comment: I found this issue, there was an application override of HTTP 302 response from login result with a big shiny TODO. 
I am closing this because the issue is not related to IdentityServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was inside our application and not inside Identity Server